# Programmatically add LayoutAnchorable to DockManager

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm attempting to programmatically add a new `LayoutAnchorable` to my AvalonDock `DockingManager` instance.

Using the below code, the anchorable appears, but is blank (the content doesn't show), and the buttons do not work (float, autohide, close, etc).

The control *does* start working as intended after dragging it (at runtime) into and out of my `LayoutDocumentPane`, although the close button doesn't appear (which is a separate issue).

```
var anchorable = new LayoutAnchorable
{
    Content = control,
    Title = "Configuration",
    ContentId = "ConfigurationId",
    IsActive = true,
    IsSelected = true,
    CanFloat = true,
    CanAutoHide = false,
    CanClose = true,
    CanHide = false,
};

anchorable.AddToLayout( DockingManager, AnchorableShowStrategy.Left );
```

I've tried navigating the AvalonDock source, but there's nothing obvious that I can find.

I would like to keep this being added programmatically, rather than using MVVM.

Comment: what version of avalondock are you using? 1.3 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.

Comment: I had an issue where, if my docking manager had no panels on xaml, it would just not show the panels at all (being added at runtime as well). What I eneded up doing was adding placeholders in xaml, and remove them on app start, this did seem to do the trick somehow

Comment: Ah ok. Unfortunately I've already got a `LayoutPanel` specified.

Comment: I'm running into the same thing.  Did you find the answer?

Comment: Nope, sorry. No idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want always to add to the same pane of the document you are adding from you can do this.
`HomePage.homepage` is a static member of the window that contains the Docking manager.
`doc` is a reference to the current document.

```
LayoutDocument ld = new LayoutDocument();
ld.Content = new NewDonor(ld);
LayoutDocumentPane pane =  ((doc.FindParent<LayoutDocumentPane>() ?? (HomePage.homepage.panal.Children?[0] as LayoutDocumentPane)) ?? new LayoutDocumentPane());
pane.Children.Add(ld);
if (HomePage.homepage.panal.ChildrenCount == 0)
{
    HomePage.homepage.panal.Children.Add(pane);
}
ld.IsSelected = true;
```